# Passing data to Twitter Bootstrap Modal when using Codeigniter table library

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, modal-dialog

I have a problem with my code.

I am currently loading my list of accounts through a database and generating a table with Codeigniters library, table.

```
$this->load->library('table');

$this->db->select('firstname, lastname, accountname, registerdate, birthdate, email');
$this->db->from('accounts');

$query = $this->db->get();

$template = array('table_open' => '<table class="table table-striped table-hover">');
$headings = array( 'Fornavn', 'Efternavn', 'Brugernavn', 'Registeringsdato', 'Fødselsdag', 'Email');
$this->table->set_template($template);
$this->table->set_heading($headings);

return $this->table->generate($query);
```

I would like a modal to open when clicking on the table row. My only headtwister is how I pass any data, like userid, to the modal opened? I can change the table template to open a modal but I cannot figure out how to pass the data. Since the data should be an id which changes from row to row, if you catch my drift.

I hope theres some smart brain out there who can help me!

Best regards
OrKarstoft

Answer (score 0):

Initialize some `id` for `'table-open'`. Then use jQuery on view side, when table is ready to insert attribute. Try this:

`//controller`

```
$template = array('table_open' => '<table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="myTable">');
```

`//view`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myTable tr").each(function(index){
        $(this).attr('id', 'row_' + index);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do this in the view with javascript!

Basic concept:

- Attach a click listener to the table rows.
- Use `data-` tags on the `<tr>`'s or DOM traversal to collect the row's data that you want to send to the modal.
- Write the data to your modal template
- Show the modal.

I put together a jsFiddle for you to illustrate all the parts. [Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/1ckw8akg/1/)

To add the extra tags into your rows using the codeigniter table library, you are going to have to change the way you generate the table a little bit.

```
foreach($query as $row)
{
    $this->table->add_row('see codeigniter docs');
}
$this->table->generate();
```

[Codeigniter add_row() Documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/table.html#CI_Table::add_row)